# ODP.NET and Entity Framework Not Cooperating with Float Values

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net

I have an odd issue that is occurring with ODP.NET when it is accessing a float column in a database table.  I am using Entity Framework to generate my models (code first) and I am then trying to scaffold a controller and set of views with it.  When I create the model, I notice that Entity Framework and ODP.NET create the float data type this way in the C# class:

```
[Column(TypeName = "float")]
public decimal? DBVALUE { get; set; }
```

Presumably it does it like this because the float has a high precision? However, this is causing an error when I try to run scaffolding. When I take out that column specifier and just do it as a straight-up float in C#, it seems to work fine.  However, that worries me about the precision of the value.  Any idea whether it is ODP.NET or entity framework that does this?  What is the best way to handle precision for values that are of type float in the database when using ODP.NET?